# Should I write unit test for void methods (includes repository call)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, springmockito

I have the following code snippets in my spring boot application:

```java
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository ...) {...}

    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdateUser(UserDAO user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

Test case class:

```java
class UserServiceImplUnitTest  {

    private UserRepository userRepository = mock(UserRepository.class);

    private UserService userService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        userService = new UserServiceImpl(userRepository);
    }
}
```

I am using mockito to write my test cases. However, for this void method should i write test case(s)? If yes, how can i write it?

Comment: Counter-question: why does `saveOrUpdateUser(...)` return `void` instead of, for example, the updated entity? --- As an aside: the term `DAO` seems to be misused here. A DAO is an alternative to a repository, i.e. something that handles entities.

Comment: How Can you test your code works as intended?! Your api is not good enough.

Comment: @Turing85, there is no specific reason, I can say that it returns void because i have nothing to do with the returned value. Should i return smth?

Comment: I do not understand how you could not want to return the updated entity. If this snippet of code is, for example, used as part of a `PUT` or `PATCH` request, I'd want to return the updated entity in the response body.

Comment: @Turing85, there is no reason to return anything for my mvc application (by the way, it is not an api)

Comment: Then you have still the option to `verify(...)` that the repository was called with the expected value. Whether this is test-worthy or not is for you to decide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You should mainly focus on whether `UserServiceImpl` interacts with `UserRepository` in an expected way such as the things like if it invokes the correct method on the `UserRepository` with the correct arguments etc.

By using Mockito to mock the `UserRepository` , you may end up with a test something like as follows :

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UserServiceImplUnitTest  {

    @Mock
    UserRepository userRepository ;

    UserService userService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        userService = new UserServiceImpl(userRepository);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSaveOrUpdateUser(){
        UserDAO user = createDummyUser();
        userService.saveOrUpdateUser(user);

        verify(userRepository).save(same(user));
    }
}
```